# Align the content to the center using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am trying tkinter for the first time. I want to align all the input box and the contents to the middle of the dialogue box.Currently, it is in the left side. I want the whole thing in the image to be at the center from top and bottom as well.

Here is the image of the output I am currently getting.

[image].

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    _root = Tk()

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("TButton", foreground="black", background="seashell3")
    _root.title('Image Compression using K-means Clustering')
    _root.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)

    _mainframe = ttk.Frame(_root, padding='5 5 5 5')
    _mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(E, W, N, S))

    _url_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(_mainframe, text='URL', padding='5 5 5 5')
    _url_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(E, W),columnspan=2)
    _url_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    _url_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    _url = StringVar()
    _url.set('http://')
    _url_entry = ttk.Entry(_url_frame, width=100, textvariable=_url)
    _url_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(E, W, S, N), padx=5)
    _fetch_btn = ttk.Button(_url_frame, text='Fetch info from URL', command=fetch_url)

    _fetch_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5)

    _img_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(_mainframe, text='Content', padding='9 0 0 0')
    _img_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W),columnspan=2)
    _images = StringVar()
    _img_listbox = Listbox(_img_frame, listvariable=_images, height=6, width=100, selectmode='multiple')
    _img_listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(E, W), pady=5)
    _img_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', fetch_selected_images)

    _scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(_img_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=_img_listbox.yview)
    _scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(S, N), pady=6)
    _img_listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=_scrollbar.set)

    _radio_frame = ttk.Frame(_img_frame)
    _radio_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

    _choice_lbl = ttk.Label(_radio_frame, text='')
    _choice_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    _save_method = StringVar()
    _save_method.set('img')

    _img_only_radio = ttk.Radiobutton(_radio_frame, text='As Images', variable=_save_method, value='img')
    _img_only_radio.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=2, sticky=W)
    _img_only_radio.configure(state='normal')

    _scrape_btn = ttk.Button(_mainframe, text='Scrape!', command=save,style='TButton')
    _scrape_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(N,E), pady=2)

    _compress_btn = ttk.Button(_mainframe, text='Compress!', command=compress)
    _compress_btn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2)

    _status_frame = ttk.Frame(_root, relief='sunken', padding='2 2 2 2')
    _status_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(E, W, S))
    _status_msg = StringVar()
    _status_msg.set('Type a URL to start scraping...')
    _status = ttk.Label(_status_frame, textvariable=_status_msg, anchor=W)
    _status.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(E, W))

    # context menu

    _menubar = Menu(_root)
    filemenu = Menu(_menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label='Fetch images from URL', command=fetch_url)
    filemenu.add_command(label='Scrape images', command=save)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Compress image", command=compress)
    filemenu.add_separator()
```

Comment: I don't think `tkinter` supports what you're looking for. You could render text centered,  but having an input box with centered text (that stays centered during input) may not be (easily) possible.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the root window you must tell it how to react to size changes:

```
_root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
_root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

which means to expand row 0 and column 0 with the window.

Then to center the `_mainframe` just put it in the window without any sticky:

```
_mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
```